# PHP Timetable Issue - While Loop Issue

Tags: php, html

I'm making a simple PHP timetabling website. I've made a table and I have the times in a horizontal header and just Monday at the moment but i want to add 5 days, Monday to Friday. I'm just unsure of how to put the correct data in the correct times and day.

My database has id, name, startTime, endTime and Day

Some data could be 0, Basketball, 9:15, 10:15, Mon.

1, Tennis, 10:15, 11:15, Mon.

2, Cricket, 11:15, 12:15 Tue.

I currently have a while loop that can fill in the table, but not in the
correct slots (td).
Here is my table code so far:

```
<?php 

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '******';
$db = 'test';
$error = 'Error Connecting to database';
$error1 = 'Error Selecting to database';   
$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die($error);
$select_db = mysql_select_db($db) or die($error1);

?>

<table border="1px">
<tr>
<div class="differentLine">
<th >&nbsp;</th>
<th > 9:15 - 10:15 </th>
<th > 10:15 - 11:15 </th>
<th > 11:15 - 12:15 </th>
<th > 12:15 - 13:15 </th>
<th > 13:15 - 14:15 </th>
<th > 14:15 - 15:15 </th>
<th > 15:15 - 16:15 </th>
<th > 16:15 - 17:15 </th>
<th > 17:15 - 18:15 </th>
</div>
</tr >

<tr>
<th >Monday </th>   


<?php
$sqlip = "Select * From Modules";
$query = mysql_query($sqlip) or die("Error");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $day = $row['Day'];
    $start_time = $row['Start_Time'];
    $End_Time = $row['End_Time'];

    if($start_time == "9:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "10:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "11:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "12:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "13:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "14:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "15:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "16:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "17:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}


echo "</tr>";



}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things.

Why do you have

```
<tr>
<th >Monday </th>
```

this isn't being database fed, you need to automate that and put it on a

if you want to dynamically print

1, Tennis, 10:15, 11:15, Mon.

you need to have html aligned this way.

```
<tr><th><?=$order?>,</th> <th><?=$sports?>,</th><th><?=$timing?></th><th><?=$day?></th></tr>
```

You should also use `switch and case` statements instead of `if statements` to take up less code.

You also have `$name2` which is printing a variable which doesn't have any value assigned to it; maybe you want to use `$name` instead to match up the td's, it looks like `$name` has a value of `$row['Name']` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Calendars/timetables are easily created in php when using arrays and loops. Here is how I would do it.

First, create the array and times-

```
//an array of all your start/end times
$times = array(
    array('start'=>'9:15', 'end'=>'10:15'),
    array('start'=>'10:15', 'end'=>'11:15'),
    array('start'=>'11:15', 'end'=>'12:15'),
    array('start'=>'12:15', 'end'=>'13:15'),
    array('start'=>'13:15', 'end'=>'14:15'),
    array('start'=>'14:15', 'end'=>'15:15'),
    array('start'=>'15:15', 'end'=>'16:15'),
    array('start'=>'16:15', 'end'=>'17:15'),
    array('start'=>'17:15', 'end'=>'18:15')
);
```

Now you can build your header using a loop-

```
<table border="1px">
    <tr class="differentLine">
        <th >&nbsp;</th>

    <?php foreach($times as $time){
        echo '<th > '.$time['start'].' - '.$time['end'].' </th>';
    } ?>

    </tr >
```

Second, create an array of the days-

```
//use the short version (Mon, Tue, etc) as keys, as that is what you show in your data
//and use the long version for displaying
$days = array('Mon'=>'Monday', 'Tue'=>'Tuesday', 'Wed'=>'Wednesday', 'Thu'=>'Thursday', 'Fri'=>'Friday');
```

Now you can build your rows using a loop-

```
<?php foreach($days as $short=>$long){ ?>
    <tr>
        <th > <?php echo $long; ?> </th>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Third, create an array of your database data-

```
// order your database data by the Day and Start_Time
<?php
$sqlip = "Select * From Modules ORDER BY Day, Start_Time";
$query = mysql_query($sqlip) or die("Error");

// create an array to hold your data
$events = array();

// loop through your database rows and add to the array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    //add the row to the array, using the Day as a key and the Start_time as a key
    $events[$row['Day']][$row['Start_Time']] = $row;
}
```

Now you have an array that would look like-

```
$events = array(
    'Mon'=> array(
        '9:15' => array('id'=>0, 'name'=>'Basketball', 'startTime'=>'9:15', 'endTime'=>'10:15', 'Day'=>'Mon'),
        '10:15' => array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'Tennis', 'startTime'=>'10:15', 'endTime'=>'11:15', 'Day'=>'Mon')
    ),
    'Tue'=> array(
        '11:15' => array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'Cricket', 'startTime'=>'11:15', 'endTime'=>'12:15', 'Day'=>'Wed')
    )
);
```

Fourth, now in your day row loop, loop through each time array, and check if an event array exists-

```
<?php foreach($days as $short=>$long){ ?>
    <tr>
        <th > <?php echo $long; ?> </th>

        <?php
        // check if there are any events for this day
        if(isset($events[$short])){
            //since there are events for this day, loop through all the times
            foreach($times as $k=>$time){
                //check if there is an event at this time
                if(isset($events[$short][$time['start']])){
                    //echo the event
                    echo '<td>'.$events[$short][$time['start']]['name'].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    //since no event, echo blank cell
                    echo '<td></td>';
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // since no events for the day, create blank cells for each time
            for($t=0;$t<count($times);$t++){
                echo '<td></td>';
        }
    } ?>
    </tr>';
<?php } ?>
```

---

Now when you put it all together it would look like -

```
<?php 
//your database connection
...
//

//an array of all your start/end times
$times = array(
    array('start'=>'9:15', 'end'=>'10:15'),
    array('start'=>'10:15', 'end'=>'11:15'),
    array('start'=>'11:15', 'end'=>'12:15'),
    array('start'=>'12:15', 'end'=>'13:15'),
    array('start'=>'13:15', 'end'=>'14:15'),
    array('start'=>'14:15', 'end'=>'15:15'),
    array('start'=>'15:15', 'end'=>'16:15'),
    array('start'=>'16:15', 'end'=>'17:15'),
    array('start'=>'17:15', 'end'=>'18:15')
);

//use the short version (Mon, Tue, etc) as keys, as that is what you show in your data
//and use the long version for displaying
$days = array('Mon'=>'Monday', 'Tue'=>'Tuesday', 'Wed'=>'Wednesday', 'Thu'=>'Thursday', 'Fri'=>'Friday');

// order your database data by the Day and Start_Time
<?php
$sqlip = "Select * From Modules ORDER BY Day, Start_Time";
$query = mysql_query($sqlip) or die("Error");

// create an array to hold your data
$events = array();

// loop through your database rows and add to the array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    //add the row to the array, using the Day as a key and the Start_time as a key
    $events[$row['Day']][$row['Start_Time']] = $row;
} ?>

<table border="1px">
    <tr class="differentLine">
        <th >&nbsp;</th>

    <?php foreach($times as $time){
        echo '<th > '.$time['start'].' - '.$time['end'].' </th>';
    } ?>

    </tr >

<?php foreach($days as $short=>$long){ ?>
    <tr>
        <th > <?php echo $long; ?> </th>

        <?php
        // check if there are any events for this day
        if(isset($events[$short])){
            //since there are events for this day, loop through all the times
            foreach($times as $k=>$time){
                //check if there is an event at this time
                if(isset($events[$short][$time['start']])){
                    //echo the event
                    echo '<td>'.$events[$short][$time['start']]['name'].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    //since no event, echo blank cell
                    echo '<td></td>';
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // since no events for the day, create blank cells for each time
            for($t=0;$t<count($times);$t++){
                echo '<td></td>';
        }
    } ?>
    </tr>';
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mysql_ function, its insecured and deprecated, use mysqli or pdo instead

In addition, all this code can change to 3 rows:

```
$times_array = array("9:15","11:15","12:15","13:15","14:15","15:15","16:15","17:15")
$row = in_array($start_time,$times_array)?$name2:"";
echo "<td>".$row."</td>";
```

========================

```
if($start_time == "9:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "10:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "11:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "12:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "13:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "14:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "15:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "16:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}

if($start_time == "17:15"){
    echo"<td> $name2</td>";
} else {
    echo"<td> </td>";
}
```